# Angular6 Typescript Signalr: Not getting any event though the Client is connected to the SignalR Hub

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, signalr-hub

I have created a SignalR hub with Web API and Angular UI.

The expected outcome is to connect Angular UI with SignalR hub and at any event happened on the Server the angular client should be notified on the respective event name.

Code for angular hub is:

```
 public openChannel(url: string): void {

    this.hubConnection = $.hubConnection(url, {"useDefaultPath": true});
    this.hubProxy = this.hubConnection.createHubProxy('employeeHub');
    this.hubConnection.logging = true; 
    **this.hubProxy.on('displayStatus',  (channel: string) => {
        console.log('worked', channel);
    });**

    this.hubConnection.start(this.options).done((data: any) => {

        console.log('Connected to Processing Hub');
        this.sendMessage();
    }).catch((error: any) => {
        console.log('Hub error -> ' + error);
    });;
}
```

and its calling method is:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLGEData();
    this._signalrService.openChannel('http://localhost/RealTimeNotify/Hubs');
   }
```

It displays the console message "Connected to processing hub" but the highlighted code doesn't display any console message when something happens at Server side.

Server side code is working fine with the jQuery, when we use the following code to get updations:

```
    $(function () {

        // Proxy created on the fly
        var emp = $.connection.employeeHub;

        // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
        emp.client.displayStatus = function () {
            getData();
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();
    });
```

Let me know, if more information is required in this context.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The angular method `on('displayStatus',  (channel: string) => {` is expecting a string parameter, whereas the jQuery method is not expecting any parameters at all. Did you try making the angular to be parameterless as well?

Answer (score 0):

It worked automatically, may be because of Cache or some other reason, because when i made changes in the same page, they were reflected in the UI.

But the event was not captured till the time i modified it to:

```
this.hubProxy.on('displayStatus',  (channel: string) => {
    alert('abc');
    console.log('worked', channel);
});
```

Just putting the alert made the cache refresh or something may be.